# Config information for a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am working on a gem that needs to be configured with a hostname, username, and password. I would prefer to store this configuration information in config/directoryservices.yml

How do I make my gem automatically create this file when installed?

I've seen a lot of places say that config information should be passed as hashes with gems. The main use of this gem will be in an app that is installed on ~15 servers. Each server will need different config information.

If it is better to include the YAML code in the app and then pass the data as a hash to the gem, I can do that, but I would still like pointers on the best way to do that.

An example of a gem that uses this kind of config is activeldap

Comment: FYI: The [twelve-factor methodology](http://12factor.net) recommends to store configuration in environment variables. See: http://12factor.net/config

Comment: Is there a tutorial on using environment variables to store config?

Comment: There might be tutorials (google should provide you plenty of code examples), but a look at the `ENV` class should be sufficient (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/ENV.html). Accessing an environment variable is as simple as `ENV['my_fancy_environment_variable']`

Comment: While I have marked JiriKolarik's answer as correct due to it answering the primary question of "How do I make my gem automatically create this file, I am actually using Environment variables to configure my app since that is the new recommended practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If are you working on rails gem, you can create [install generator](https://github.com/werein/foundationstone/blob/master/lib/generators/foundationstone/install_generator.rb) which will copy default [config file](https://github.com/werein/foundationstone/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/foundationstone.yml) and then [load it](https://github.com/werein/foundationstone/blob/master/lib/foundationstone/config.rb) into your app.